# Orthogonal Projection into a set

Tags: orthogonality

If $D$ is the set of matrices in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ such as each column has an $l_2$ norm less than or equal to one.
If I have a matrix $M\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ how can I make the orthogonal projection?

Since $D$ is not a vector space I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Do you mean the orthogonal projection onto the span of the columns of $M$ given a matrix $M \in D$?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the following.

You can endow $\Bbb R^{n\times m}$ by a norm (for instance, by the standard Euclidean). Since $D$ is a convex compact set, each point $M\in\Bbb R^{n\times m}$ has a unique closest to it point $p(M)\in D$. So we may consider map $p(M)$ as an orthogonal projection of $\Bbb R^{n\times m}$ onto the set $D$.